# USB 3.0 PCI card

Tags: 18.04, usb

I just picked up a USB 3.0 expansion card for my server. It appears to be detected but none of the devices plugged into it are.

```
$ lspci | grep -i usb
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 06)
03:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)


$ lsusbBus
002 Device 005: ID 045e:02d5 Microsoft Corp. Xbox One Digital TV Tuner
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:2001 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard HID Support
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:1001 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard Hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1b1c:1b05 Corsair
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0557:2221 ATEN International Co., Ltd Winbond Hermon
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I bought the card specifically for my xbox tuners. There should be 4 listed but it only shows the one thats plugged into a mobo USB port.
I tried a mouse and a keyboard on the card but neither worked.
You can see a USB 3.0 hub is detected.

Not really sure what to try.
Any help is appreciated.
Chris

Answer (score 3):

Typically after asking the question I found the answer...
I booted into [Hirens boot CD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) and ran [this utility](https://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=352&func=fileinfo&id=3495&lang=en) to update the cards firmware.
Booted back into Ubuntu and now USB devices are detected.

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering your own question.  After 24 hours, you can accept your answer, too.  And now it's accessible for anyone else who might have the same problem (and your solution is likely to apply for later Ubuntu versions, too, for several years at least).